# Can't get embedded videos to play in Chrome even though allow=autoplay has been exposed in the iframe chain

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

We are having a problem getting videos to play in a multi-nested iframe application. We're fully aware of the Chrome autoplay policies detailed at:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

This same problem does not occur in Firefox.

While we build a new consolidated application, we are framing our old sites to prove out our value proposition. One of the sites is a video site which is used to frame/wrap youtube (or vimeo, etc) videos to place a video play wrapper on top (let's call it siteV for video). This site is embedded in another site (let's call it siteL for learning). All of this is then wrapped in a top-level portal (let's call this siteA). So the relationship is:

```
siteA wraps
   siteL wraps
      siteV wraps
         Youtube video
```

The basic iframe structure is as follows, starting at **siteA **(the top level):

```
**site A**

  <iframe width="1306" height="100%" src="**siteL**" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; **autoplay**; camera; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; microphone" allowfullscreen="" class="jsx-3934071539 w-full mt-10 mx-5">

      <iframe width="100%" height="600" src="**siteV**" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; **autoplay**; camera; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; microphone" allowfullscreen="">

          <iframe class="flex-grow embed-view" allow="accelerometer; **autoplay**; camera; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; microphone" allowfullscreen="1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="**siteV**">

              <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="The Worlds Best Porsche Restomods Are Built Here!" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-_dz-7N9k_M?autoplay=0&amp;mute=1&amp;controls=0&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2F33bd-142-196-126-48.ngrok.io&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;widget_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fralicentral.jubiplatform-dev.com%2F&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;widgetid=1" id="widget2">

              </iframe>

          </iframe>

      </iframe>

  </iframe>
```

If you follow the chain down you will see that "autoplay" has been delegated down the chain in all iframe's and mute=1 is set in the query parameter to the youtube video. Our video site is utilizing the react-player npm latest version but we don't feel this is an issue.

If we set muted=true in the ReactPlayer element, the video plays just fine when hitting play but we cannot gain any control over the volume/mute button. We have have been playing with the react player integration code to try to mute and then unmute upon loading the video as the user presses play taking into consideration the autoplay and mute rules but the video will only jump forward screen increments at a time while pausing pauses with:

Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before.

This same test in Chrome does NOT fail if we bypass the framing from **siteA** and log directly into **siteL**. This, of course, removes one level of iframe nesting so that it looks more like:

```
**siteL**

  <iframe width="100%" height="600" src="**siteV**" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; **autoplay**; camera; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; microphone" allowfullscreen="">

      <iframe class="flex-grow embed-view" allow="accelerometer; **autoplay**; camera; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; microphone" allowfullscreen="1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="**siteV**">

          <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="The Worlds Best Porsche Restomods Are Built Here!" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-_dz-7N9k_M?autoplay=0&amp;mute=1&amp;controls=0&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2F33bd-142-196-126-48.ngrok.io&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;widget_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fralicentral.jubiplatform-dev.com%2F&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;widgetid=1" id="widget2">

          </iframe>

      </iframe>

  </iframe>
```

Removing this extra nesting level and things seem to work fine.

Does anyone know if there is a nesting **depth ** in force in addition to the autoplay policy enforced in Chrome?

Again, this all works fine in Firefox. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

We have tried many iterations of code changes in react player integration to get chrome to play videos embedded to a 4th level. It seems as the level of nesting in Chrome gets deeper, the autoplay policies are no longer followed. Is there perhaps a Chrome bug?

Comment: An additional comment: The problem can be recreated also simply using https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe and framing "siteL" as follows:

<iframe width="100%" height="480" src="https://jubiplatform-dev.com" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; camera; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; microphone" allowfullscreen></iframe>

In all cases if we set the ReactPlayer muted=true, video plays with no sound. It always just seems as if once we add this extra level of nesting the problem seems to occur.

Answer (score 1):

We fixed the problem. Our top-level iframe needed to have the next level (siteL) domain specified in the `allow="autoplay"` setting as follows:

```
allow="autoplay 'self' https://<subdomain>.siteL.com"
```

Because wildcard subdomains won't work for this purpose, our fix will involve dynamically rendering the iframe HTML with the correct subdomain specification of the scheme and host.

It's really too bad that the browser console didn't clearly specify what was blocked and why like Content Security Policy violations do.